# Fetching 3rd party packages for a released version via git

Tags: git

I have downloaded a release package of mxnet and it seems that the package doesn't contain 3rdparty/ folder.

```
$ ls -a
.             CMakeLists.txt   .github      Makefile       prepare_mkldnn.sh  snapcraft.yaml
..            CODEOWNERS       .gitignore   matlab         prepare_mkl.sh     snap.python
3rdparty      CONTRIBUTORS.md  .gitmodules  MKL_README.md  python             src
amalgamation  cpp-package      include      .mxnet_root    README.md          tests
appveyor.yml  DISCLAIMER       Jenkinsfile  NEWS.md        readthedocs.yml    tools
benchmark     docker           KEYS         NOTICE         R-package          .travis.yml
ci            docs             LICENSE      perl-package   scala-package
cmake         example          make         plugin         setup-utils
$ ls 3rdparty/mkldnn/
$
```

How can I add them from github?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directories in `3rdparty/` are [submodules](https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/blob/master/.gitmodules). To clone them with initial clone you should have run

```
git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet.git
```

See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---recurse-submodulesltpathspec

Now when you've already run the initial clone you just need to pull the submodules separately:

```
git pull --recurse-submodules
```

See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#Documentation/git-pull.txt---no-recurse-submodulesyeson-demandno